# WPF C#, Create moving Soap Bubbles

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, physics-engine

I am trying to create a WPF application "a game" where i have soap bubbles "i used ellipses to represent it" moving on a canvas and i can pop them with the mouse clicks.

Any idea how to get the natural movement of soap bubbles ? i have them moving but only from bottom to top. any idea how can i get like a library that helps in this..

Answer (score 3):

http://bubbleburst.codeplex.com/

This code is written by [Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/) the WPF Guru to demonstrate MVVM in his excellent book "[Advanced MVVM](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/)".

BubbleBurst code has very nice animation for simulating bubble movement. I have run the game and the animation is amazing.

IMO, Your soap bubble movement will be similar to this.

Comment: breaks the adjoining bubbles of same color, but remaining bubbles have natural movement. Break any group of bubbles in bottom right to check the effect

Comment: This code is not for SOAP bubbles, you know the soap bubbles that is used with children to play with it, that is what i mean, but thank you :)